# AR shock model solved using estimation

Tags: python, augmented-reality

I am looking at a demand-shock given by AR(1) in logs,

```
\log \kappa_{t} = \rho \log \kappa_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t},\,\,\, \epsilon_{t+1} \sim \mathcal{N}    (-0.5\sigma_{\epsilon}^2,\sigma_{\epsilon})
```

Any hiring or firing implies a fixed adjustment cost, $\iota > 0 $.
Future profits are discounted with a monthly factor of $R \in (0,1)$.

The initial demand shock is $\kappa_{-1} = 1$ and the planning horizon is 10 years, i.e. 120 months so $t \in {0,1,2,\dots,119}$. Initially you don't have any employees, $\ell_{-1}=0$

I am given this information:

The *ex post* value of the salon is *conditional* on the shock series is:

```
$$
h(\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_{119}) = \left[\sum_{t=0}^{119}R^{-t}\left[\kappa_{t}\ell_{t}^{1-\eta}-w\ell_{t}-\boldsymbol{1}_{\ell_{t}\neq\ell_{t-1}}\iota\right]\right]
$$
```

The *ex ante* expected value of the salon can be approximated by

```
$$
H = \mathbb{E}[h(\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_{119})] \approx \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=0}^{K} h(\epsilon_0^k,\epsilon_1^k,\dots,\epsilon_{119}^k)
$$
```

where each $k\in{0,1,\dots,K-1}$ is a random shock series. Maximizing profitability means maximizing $H$.

with Baseline parameters are:

```
- $\rho = 0.90$
- $\iota = 0.01$
- $\sigma_{\epsilon} = 0.10$
- $R = \left(1+0.01\right)^{1/12}$

I want to calculate $H$ if the policy  $\ell_{t}=\left(\frac{(1-\eta)\kappa_{t}}{w}\right)^{\frac{1}{\eta}}$ from question 1 is followed. Choose $K$ so the approximation is good enough to not affect your results substantially.

I have tried this, but i am not sure that it is correct because of the Monte Carlo simulation. Therefore i was wondering if it looks correct.


# Baseline parameters
    rho = 0.90
    iota = 0.01
    sigma_epsilon = 0.10
    R = (1 + 0.01)**(1/12)
    T = 120
    w = 1.0
    eta = 0.5

# Set the number of shock series
    K = 10000

# Initialize the array to store h values
    h_values = np.empty(K)

# Define the policy function
    def policy(kappa):
    return ((1 - eta) * kappa / w)**(1 / eta)

# Function to calculate the demand shock kappa
    def calculate_kappa(epsilon, kappa_minus1):
    return rho * kappa_minus1 + epsilon

# Function to calculate the profit
    def calculate_profit(l, kappa, l_minus1):
    return np.abs(kappa * l**(1 - eta) - w * l - (l != l_minus1) * iota)

# Perform the Monte Carlo simulation
    for k in range(K):
    # Simulate the shock series
    epsilon_values = np.random.normal(loc=-0.5 * sigma_epsilon**2, scale=sigma_epsilon, size=T)

    # Initialize the values
    kappa_values = np.empty(T)
    l_values = np.empty(T)

    # Initialize the initial shock and policy
    kappa_values[0] = np.exp(epsilon_values[0])
    l_values[0] = policy(kappa_values[0])

    # Simulate the model
    for t in range(1, T):
        kappa_values[t] = calculate_kappa(epsilon_values[t], kappa_values[t-1])
        l_values[t] = policy(kappa_values[t])

    # Calculate h for this shock series
    h_values[k] = np.sum(R**(-np.arange(T)) * calculate_profit(l_values, kappa_values,     np.concatenate(([0], l_values[:-1]))))

# Calculate the expected value of the salon
    H = np.mean(h_values)

    print("Expected value of the salon (K = 10000):", H)
```

Comment: There is no MathJax in Stack Overflow so the formatting of your question is unclear.